# App keeps crashing trying to set image bitmap

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview

I have two activites: one where I take a picture and another where it will display the photo.

On camera activity results I set a bitmap to the cached image as follows:

```
m.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
m.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
p=m.getDrawingCache();
```

And then when creating an intent for the new Activity I pass this bitmap:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, shopList.class);
intent.putExtra("data", p);
startActivity(intent);
```

And on the new activity I set the imageview I want to link to the new bitmap:

```
Bitmap p = (Bitmap) getIntent().getParcelableExtra("data");
ImageView m = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.listA);
m.setImageBitmap(p);
```

But when running the app it will crash when trying to set the imageview to the new bitmap and gives the following error:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.ImageView.setImageBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap)' on a
>   null object reference

I am not sure why its doing this as the initial camera activity results displays the photo correctly.

Any help is appreciated.

Edit:
The XML for the second activity imageview I am trying to set is:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/listA"
    android:layout_width="97dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.019"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
```

Comment: `m` is `null`. Your layout does not have an `ImageView` with `android:id="@+id/listA"`.

Comment: Check that `listA` exists in your view, make sure you aren't calling this before `setContentView`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: android:id="@+id/listA" is in the new activity.  listA does exist and isn't called before setting the layout.

Comment: Post layout xml of your new activity

Comment: Ok i've updated the original post.

Comment: The cache isn't working.  I tried directly setting p to bitmap and it worked.